# Rolling mean on pandas data frame timeseries

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am using Pandas to handle some Timeseries data. I have a data frame in the following format:

```
               Date      Time  Reading
552726   2016/08/01   0: 0: 0    17.28
552727   2016/08/01   0: 0: 5    17.28
552728   2016/08/01   0: 0:10    17.21
552729   2016/08/01   0: 0:15    17.16
552730   2016/08/01   0: 0:20    17.11
552731   2016/08/01   0: 0:25    17.08
552732   2016/08/01   0: 0:30    17.18
552733   2016/08/01   0: 0:35    17.18
etc...
```

I want to average the Reading column, so that it takes a 10 minute window and calculates the average, and I want to move this window across the time series. Then I want the data frame to be updated with the new averaged values, and also the Timestamp, so it would look like this:

```
           Date       Time      Reading
552726   2016/08/01   0: 0: 0    17.30
552727   2016/08/01   0: 10:0    17.35
552728   2016/08/01   0: 20:0    17.20
etc...
```

What is the best way to do this in Pandas? I tried the rolling mean method setting up a frequency for the rolling window. But then I have to rebuild the data frame, with new timestamps myself, and I think there's a cleaner, easier way to do this.

Thank you, and please let me know if I can clarify things better.

Comment: do you always have an observation every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes. Sampling rate is 1 sample / 5 seconds

Comment: Then why don't you use a 120 observation rolling window?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't update the Date and Time. It calculates the mean, but it doesn't update my dataframe. I basically get a bunch of NANs and then the averaged values. So I would have to pull those, and create a new series with the proper timestamps. I wanted to know if there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data, say I wanted to calculate average of 15 seconds intervals.
I simply did:

```
#frame contains your data  
n_obs = 3
result = frame.rolling(window = n_obs, min_periods = 1).mean().iloc[::n_obs,:]

#          Date     Time    Reading
# 0  2016/08/01  0: 0: 0  17.280000
# 3  2016/08/01  0: 0:15  17.216667
# 6  2016/08/01  0: 0:30  17.123333
```

Where the main "trick" is selecting the observations multiple of n_obs.

This should work for you using n_obs = 120, although it implies calculating many more averages than you actually need.

Comment: Glad it helped. 
Also consider upvoting if you found the answer useful ;)

One problem i found is the representation of time with hours and mins having 1 or 2 digits.This is problematic in the conversion to datetime...

Should that be useful,I did this "messy" line to get times in a nice format (as lists in the example, but you can easily convert to pandas Series). You can play with it to understand each step

    time = frame.Time.values.tolist()
    time = map(lambda x: ":".join(x), [map(lambda x: "{0:0>2}".format(x), el.split(":")) for el in map(lambda x: x.replace(" ", ""), time)])

Comment: thanks. I am new to Pandas. that's what I was doing, but I am still getting use to the iloc method for indexing.